# CacheStorage.open() returning undefined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-cache

I have a service worker on my hobby site with an `install` event hander that looks like this (in TypeScript):

```
/**
 * When the service worker is being intalled, download the required assets into a temporary cache
 * @param e The intall event
 */
function installHander(e: ExtendableEvent): void {
    "use strict";
    // Put updated resources in a new cache, so that currently running pages
    // get the current versions.
    e.waitUntil(caches.delete("core-waiting").then(() => {
        return caches.open("core-waiting").then((core) => {
            const resourceUrls = [
                "/",
                "/loading/",
                "/offline/",
                "/css/site.css",
                "/js/site.js"
            ];

            return Promise.all(resourceUrls.map((key) => {
                // Make sure to download fresh versions of the files!
                return fetch(key, { cache: "no-cache" })
                .then((response) => core.put(key, response));
            }))
            // Don't wait for the client to refresh the page (as this site is designed not to refresh)
            .then(() => (self as ServiceWorkerGlobalScope).skipWaiting());
        });
    }));
}
```

In Firefox this works just fine, but Chrome 65 is returning `undefined` from `caches.open("core-waiting")`, so it's throwing an error when I try to call `put` on `core`. [According to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/open), that's supposed to be impossible. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the Google Chrome window that Visual Studio opens can't use the cache API, and just silently returns undefined. If you open a Chrome window manually, it works just fine.

There really should be a console warning about this so that devs don't waste time scratching their heads about this...

Comment: I have been searching for a fix to this since yesterday, you saved me a ton of headache. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually due to this Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1054541

Basically, the --user-data-dir switch that Visual Studio sets is "too long", and breaks the service-worker cache API in Chrome.

You should be able to work around this in Visual Studio by using the "Browse With..." option to set Chrome to launch without the custom --user-data-dir (or set your own).